# Why the Image widget can not set special width and height in the Container with specified width and height?

Tags: flutter

Why the Image widget can not set special width and height in the Container with specified width and height?

```
class HomeContent extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Image.network(
          "http://a1.att.hudong.com/60/38/01200000194369136323385641912.jpg",
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
        ),
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.yellow,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The result is like this, you see the Image in the Container take up the width `400.0`, rather than `20`.

[image]

---

**EDIT-01**

I tried use `MediaQuery` to set the Image's width and height, but there is no effect.

```
class HomeContent extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Image.network(
          "http://a1.att.hudong.com/60/38/01200000194369136323385641912.jpg",
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
        ),
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.yellow,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use** Mediaquery for`height` and `Width`

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
```

And implement like this

```
class HomeContent extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Image.network(
          "http://a1.att.hudong.com/60/38/01200000194369136323385641912.jpg",
          width: width,
          height: height,
        ),
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.yellow,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand your meaning. I can not set a specified width to the Image widget?

Comment: @244boy you can add or divide size by calculating its size or if you want size same as a container then look I updated my code

Comment: In this case, is the `context ` represent the `Container `?

Comment: obviously just put MediaQuery's height and width in build mathod

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Container's Constants first:

Such as set the `alignment`.

```
class HomeContent extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Image.network(
          "http://a1.att.hudong.com/60/38/01200000194369136323385641912.jpg",
          width: 20,
          height:20,
        ),
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.yellow,
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The width and height on `Container` sets the `width` and `height` constraints of the child, at which point the `width` and `height` on the child are powerless to do anything.So you can take another widget and place the Image inside that.For example I can take `Center`.

```
Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Image.network(
            "http://a1.att.hudong.com/60/38/01200000194369136323385641912.jpg",
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
          ),
        ),
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.yellow,
        ),
      )
```

and it'll work fine as expected